# opencv error: assertion failed with warpImage

Tags: c++, opencv

i try to execute the warping code on visual studio 2010, i have done all necessary steps  but when i try to compile ..i have this error :

OpenCV Error : Assertion failed (dim <=2 && step[0] > 0> in unknown function file ../../../ocv/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp line 647

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "CThinPlateSpline.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    // load a nice picture

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR );

    // generate some generic points
    // usually you would use a interest point detector such as SURF or SIFT
    std::vector<cv::Point> iP, iiP;

    // push some points into the vector for the source image
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(256,256));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(150,256));

    // push some point into the vector for the dst image
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(70,70));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,60));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(60,410));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,420));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(220,280));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(180,240));

    // create thin plate spline object and put the vectors into the constructor
    CThinPlateSpline tps(iP,iiP);


    // warp the image to dst
    Mat dst;
    tps.warpImage(img,dst,0.01,INTER_CUBIC,BACK_WARP);


    // show images
    cv::imshow("original",img);
    cv::imshow("distorted",dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I Have also One ccp classe and One header in my project where i define necessary methods
Can some One help me to resolve this problem please

Comment: What's your OpenCV version?

Comment: I am Using OpenCV 2.2